# Intuition behind factorisation in Schur Complement Lemma proof

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite, matrix-analysis

The theorem states:

Let $T \in \mathbb{S}^m$ be positive definite and $X \in \mathbb{S}^n$ and $U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$. Then $M$ is positive semidefinite if and only if $X - UT^{-1}U^T$ is, where

$$ M =\begin{bmatrix} T & U^T \\ U & X \end{bmatrix} $$

The proof starts off by observing that

$$ M = \begin{bmatrix}  I & 0 \\ UT^{-1} & I\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}T & 0 \\ 0 & X - UT^{-1}U^T\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  I & T^{-1}U^T \\ 0 & I\end{bmatrix}$$

and then arguing from there, but  this is the part that is unclear to me.

What is it about the theorem statement that makes it occur to you to factorise the left hand side in terms of the block diagonal on the right in the first place? Does this factorisation incidentally show up somewhere else, or is there some way one can "see" that $M$ can be factorised in such a way.

Comment: "Does this factorisation incidentally show up somewhere else" Yes, sure. It also has a name: Schur factorization. It is very helpful -- not only when it comes to positive definiteness but also invertibility. For example, if $X$ is invertible, then $M$ is invertible iff $X-UT^{-1}U^T$ is.

Comment: If you look at the quadratic form $f(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}^TM\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ and complete the square in $x$ then the relation with the factorization in question becomes obvious/straightforward.